# Regexp match spaces not followed be a specific word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have spent the last couple of hours trying to figure out how to match all whitespace (`\s`) unless followed by `AND\s` or preceded by `\sAND`.

I have this so far

```
\s(?!AND\s)
```

but it is then matching the space after `\sAND`, but I don't want that.

### [image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to match all whitespace that is not followed _or preceded_ by `AND`? Would [`(?<!\sAND)\s(?!AND\s)`](https://regex101.com/r/uI6xZ7/1) be the regex you are looking for? If it is, unfortunately that regex does not work in JavaScript.

Comment: yes, match all \s but not \sAND\s

Comment: I had a feeling I would need a lookbehind, do you know the reason they aren't supported in Javascript?

Comment: I guess a way to work around this would be to send the String to a php page, and do the splitting there, then send it back as JSON

Comment: Or a workaround can be a matching regex: [`\S+\sAND\s\S+|\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/bW3zC2/1).

Comment: I like that one better, put it down as an answer so I can select it as answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often, when you want to split by a single character that appears in specific context, you can replace the approach with a matching one.

I suggest *matching* all sequences of non-whitespace characters joined with `AND` enclosed with whitespace ones *before* and then match any other non-whitespace sequences. Thus, we'll ensure we get an array of necessary substrings:

```
\S+\sAND\s\S+|\S+
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bW3zC2/1)

*I assume the `\sAND\s` pattern appears between some non-whitespace characters.*

```js
var re = /\S+\sAND\s\S+|\S+/g; 
var str = 'split this but don\'t split this AND this';
var res = str.match(re);
document.write(JSON.stringify(res));
```

As [Alan Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20938/alan-moore) suggests, the alternation can be unrolled into [`\S+(?:\sAND\s\S+)*`](https://regex101.com/r/bW3zC2/3):

- `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace characters
- `(?:\sAND\s\S+)*` - 0 or more (thus, it is optional) sequences of...

  - `\s` - one whitespace (add `+` to match 1 or more)
  - `AND` - literal `AND` character sequence
  - `\s` - one whitespace (add `+` to match 1 or more)
  - `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace symbols.

Comment: Yes, positive matching is the way to go, but I wouldn't use alternation. `/\S+(?:\sAND\s\S+)*/g` also allows for more than two AND-ed words in a row, which I think is implicit in the question.

Comment: I agree something like that can even speed up matching a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Since JS doesn't support lookbehinds, you can use [the following trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html):

- Match `(\sAND\s)|\s`
- Throw away any match where `$1` has a value

Here's a short example which replaces the spaces you want with an underscore:

```js
var str = "split this but don't split this AND this";
str = str.replace(/(\sAND\s)|\s/g, function(m, a) {
 return a ? m : "_";
});
document.write(str);
```